# Updating linked checkboxes

Tags: excel, checkbox, updating, vba

I am struggling try to solve  an easy problem.
I have check boxes in Sheet 1 and check boxes in sheet 2 that have to assume the same value (`TRUE` or `FALSE`) of the ones in Sheet 1.
The problem is that when I open Sheet 2 they are not marked but I have to click on them with the mouse.

I'm using this code:

```
 Sheet2.chk_2A.Value = Sheet1.chk_1a.Value
```

Am I forgetting an auto update command or something similar?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: It seems to be Visual Basic for Excel..

Comment: @MarkLeiber VBA Excel

Comment: Is this code in the checkbox clicked event? Where did you put this code?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there is no need for VBA code here if you link the two check boxes to the same cell. Just assign both check boxes the same cell in `Format Control...`, `Control`, `Cell link:`. If that's not an option then you'll have to place your code into a sub and assign this sub to these check boxes upon click.

In this case your code depends if you used form controls or ActiveX controls. For Form controls you'd have to use

```
Sheet2.Shapes("chk_2A").controlformat.value = Sheet1.Shapes("chk_1a").controlformat.value
```

and for ActiveX controls your code suggestion should work if the check boxes are named correctly.

```
Sheet2.chk_2A.value = Sheet1.chk_1a.value
```

In both cases I assume that you used either form controls or ActiveX controls. If you used one form control and one ActiveX control then you'll have to adjust the above code suggestions accordingly. The following code can help you determine what you used.

```
Public Sub AllShapes()
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        Debug.Print shp.Name
        Select Case shp.Type
        Case 8
            Debug.Print "Form Control"
        Case 12
            Debug.Print "ActiveX Control"
        Case Else
            Debug.Print shp.Type
        End Select
    Next shp
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: The checkboxes are all ActiveX controls, my code works but the checkboxes don't become "TRUE" or "FALSE" automatically. I have to select them and then they change properly.

Comment: Did you disable `Application.ScreenUpdating` or `Application.Calculation` set to manual?